# Accessing array element inside ArrayList c#

Tags: c#

I have the following problem, 
When i am trying to access data from an Array inside another Array List, it dispalys that "cannot apply indexing[] with to an expression of type 'object'".

This is my code

```
public void getWaypoints() {
ArrayList potentialWPs = new ArrayList();
potentialWPs.Add(containerWaypoint.GetComponentInChildren(typeof(Transform)));
wayPoints = new ArrayList();

foreach (Transform potentialWP in potentialWPs){
    if(potentialWP.transform != containerWaypoint.transform){
        wayPoints[wayPoints.Count] = new ArrayList(2);
        wayPoints[wayPoints.Count][0] = potentialWP;                    
    }
}
```

The error are shown in the line "**wayPoints[wayPoints.Count][0]**".

Any one have any idea why this error is occurred?

Comment: `wayPoints` is 1-dimensional array not 2-dimensional array

Comment: ArrayList is deprecated - use `List<T>` (System.Collections.Generics) instead.

Comment: Why are you using ArrayList anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Since ArrayList is a non-generic collection class, all items retrieved from it are `object`s, and need to be cast to their real types, like this:

```
 foreach (Transform potentialWP in potentialWPs){
    if(potentialWP.transform != containerWaypoint.transform){
        wayPoints[wayPoints.Count] = new ArrayList(2);
        ArrayList arr = wayPoints[wayPoint.Count] as ArrayList; <-- THIS
        arr[0] = potentialWP;
    }
```

Several important things to note:

1) This would have been simpelr if you had simply created the new array and held a reference to it (the `arr` variable I introduced) and then used that to add to the wayPoints and to assign to.

2) ArrayList really is an old and primitve class. Is there a reason you don't use a `List<Transform>` instead>?

3) You have a bug in your code, since you're access the ArayList in position Count. An ArrayList of length 2, if accessed at position 2, will crash - ArrayLists are 0-based, so you need to use Count - 1 to access the last position (1) on a length 2 array.

Comment: Thx for the answer, 
yeah it's a mistake that i don't use List<Transform> instead.
i know that array based on 0, and i just access pointer 0 and 1 for each data in potentialWPs not more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `wayPoints[0] = potentialWP;` 
Since you have already declared an array list with size `wayPoints.Count` , you have to mention the index correctly.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList only holds **object** types; that why you get

```
"cannot apply indexing[] with to an expression of type 'object'"
```

You need to cast

```
wayPoints
```

to your desired type

EDIT:

You should be using

```
List<T> (System.Collections.Generics)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        wayPoints[wayPoints.Count] = new ArrayList(2);
        wayPoints[wayPoints.Count][0] = potentialWP;
```

`wayPoints[wayPoints.Count]` returns an `object`. You need to cast it, before treating it like an ArrayList:

```
((ArrayList)wayPoints[wayPoints.Count])[0] = potentialWP;
```

However, you shouldn't use ArrayList, as it's deprecated. Use List instead.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have is that by using `ArrayList` which is just a collection of objects, there is no implicit conversion to an array. As others have answered, one way is to cast the result to an array, after which you can access it by index.

A better way, might be to use a Generic `List<T>` which can be defined as a list of lists:

```
List<List<Transform>> waypoints = new List<List<Transform>>();
```

This would make your code a lot easier:

```
public void getWaypoints() {
    ArrayList potentialWPs = new ArrayList();
    potentialWPs.Add(containerWaypoint.GetComponentInChildren(typeof(Transform)));
    List<Transform[]> waypoints = new List<Transform[]>();

    foreach (Transform potentialWP in potentialWPs){
        if(potentialWP.transform != containerWaypoint.transform){
            wayPoints.Add( new List<Transform>>(){ potentialWP });                 
        }
    }
}
```

`waypoints` is now a "multi-dimensional" list of lists of `Transform`. You can access any element like so

```
List<Transform> first = waypoints[0];
```

or you could access a `Transform` directly

```
Transform firstOfFirst = waypoints[0][0];
```

or you could add another `Transform` to an existing list

```
waypoints[0].Add(anotherTransform);
```

Comment: thx, but i need to create multi dimentional array, 1st dimention for the waypoints itself which has 2 elements, 1st elements to store it's location, 2nd element to store each neighbour the waypoints have where this 2nd element is an array...

may be i'll use struct instead....

Comment: @user1855858 - It kind of did already have a multi-dimensional array, but ive updated the answer to hopefully be a bit clearer on how you would go on to use `waypoints`